# image update not read by php, null data given, laravel inertia react

Tags: php, reactjs, typescript, laravel, inertiajs

I have a CRUD system specifically for updates, I have tried to update the data and all the data is updated correctly except the images.

this is my controller code:

```
public function update_book(Request $request, $id)
    {
        // dd($request->all());
        
        $book = Book::find($id);

        $imageName = $request->file('image')->store('public/book');

        $book->update([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'date' => $request->date,
            'author' => $request->author,
            'stock' => $request->stock,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'image' => $imageName
        ]);

        $book->categories()->sync($request->categories);

        return redirect()->route('admin.books_panel')->with('success', 'Data Successfully Updated!');
    }
```

this is my react code:

```
    const [image, setImage] = useState<File | null>(null)
    const handleImageChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) {
          setImage(e.target.files[0])
        }
    }

    const updateBook = async (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        
        let cat: string[] = []
        selectedCategories.forEach(categoryId => {
            cat.push(categoryId)
        })
        
        Inertia.put(`/admin/books-panel/${book.id}`, {
            name: name,
            date: date,
            author: author,
            stock: stock,
            description: description,
            image: image as Blob,
            categories: cat.slice(1)
        })
    }
```

dd result:

```
array:7 [▼ // app\Http\Controllers\AdminController.php:114
  "name" => "ddd"
  "date" => "2024-03-05"
  "author" => "ccc"
  "stock" => 1111
  "description" => "ccc"
  "image" => null
  "categories" => array:2 [▶]
]
```

I also tried using the append method, the data from the image is exist there, but if I use this method, the controller will receive [] data(data didn't received well, including the image), here is my react function:

```
 const updateBook = async (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault()
    
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('name', name)
        formData.append('date', date)
        formData.append('author', author)
        formData.append('stock', stock)
        formData.append('description', description)
    
        if (image !== null) {
            const imageFile = new File([image], 'image.jpg')
            formData.append('image', imageFile)
        }
    
        selectedCategories.forEach(categoryId => {
            formData.append('categories[]', categoryId)
        })
    
        const payload = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries())
    
        console.log(payload)
    
        Inertia.put(`/admin/books-panel/${book.id}`, payload)
    }
```

dd result: [] // app\Http\Controllers\AdminController.php:125

console.log result:
[image: cl result]

Comment: Was create working for you to upload? What was the difference? maybe remove as Blob from `image: image as Blob,` ?

Comment: i use typescript in my code, the IDE suggest me to use it because of type checking, also it's working for the create using image as Blob.

Comment: If so, then there is a problem with your `handleImageChange` method. Check that it is actually adding the correct image. do console.log or something inside.

Comment: If controller is receiving null where you in fact actually uploaded an image. then the problem is in your frontend(react).

Comment: Or maybe your input file is not connected to the onChange of setImage (I use vue but it should be the same)

Comment: i think so, since i tried using formData.append() method, the image data was exist there, but somehow the controller didn't catch a single data from the form if i use this method.

Comment: the error in console log is because you are uploading a null image. Though you would also need the code that was answered below (when you are updating info without uploading new images) to fix the console.log error.

Comment: Now for the "unable to upload images in edit", return your code back to the original one (the same as create)

Comment: I would look at the `const handleImageChange` method. Console log inside the method to ensure that it is actually being triggered when updating the image, also console log inside `if` statement to ensure that image file is valid

Comment: i already fix the frontend and yes the problem is in here, the image data has been captured by React, however there is a slight problem in sending the image due to some laravel caching problems. So the data is not received well in the controller, but it already answering my question

Answer (score -1):

In your controller try using this method

```
public function update_book(Request $request, $id)
    {
        // dd($request->all());
        
        $book = Book::find($id);

        // $imageName = $request->file('image')->store('public/book');
        $imageName = $request->image->getClientOriginalName();
        $request->image->move(public_path('book/'),$imageName);

        $book->update([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'date' => $request->date,
            'author' => $request->author,
            'stock' => $request->stock,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'image' => $imageName
        ]);

        $book->categories()->sync($request->categories);

        return redirect()->route('admin.books_panel')->with('success', 'Data Successfully Updated!');
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think there is an issue with you processing the file and saving at the end. Also you can't `dd()` the files uploaded with `$request->all()` .

You should instead try this:

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $imageName = $request->file('image');
        // Save the image to storage or perform other operations
}
```

And if you really want to `dd()` the file input, try:

```
dd($request->file('image');
```